# SharePoint 2010 Link to Excel List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am a newbie on SharePoint 2010 and no access to server to make any config changes. Or to allow any code to run.

I am trying to create basic page where a user can click on a link to open an Excel file as a list and modify the data or add new rows.

I have created a site and a page. And added a link to the Excel document using the steps below:

1. Typed Data [[ and selected the Document Library and then the document.

The link works, but it opens Excel. I do nto want to open in Excel. I need to keep the list as I mentioned earlier. I had created it on another page as a test using the below steps and it worked. But would be nice to have a link for the user to click on.

1. Site Actions -> More Options
2. Blank & Custom
3. Import Spreadsheet.
4. Range of Cells

I need to ensure that the users cannot open the data in Excel, and create their own local version/s.

How can I do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to do this by adding an html link from Content Editor and then changing the link to point to imported Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check site contents.  You should see a the list created from the Excel file.  The Excel rows will have been copied to the new SharePoint List so you no longer need to Excel file.  Note that the Excel file and the list are not linked in anyway so changes to one will not be reflected in the other.

Comment: I did that, but when I click on the link it loads Excel instead of loading within SharePoint as a modifiable list.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have imported it or are clicking the wrong link.  can you watch the video here on how to import an Excel spreadsheet into a new SharePoint 2010 list and see if you have followed all the steps correctly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvbAo14d4xY

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly how I am importing the spreadsheet. But I want to create a link on home page that when clicked would open up the list spreadsheet on a different page.  This is because I have multiple sheets of data that I want to import so the home page would work as a navigation page.

Comment: I would either import each sheet into a new SharePoint list, or if the sheets have the same columns, import them into the same SharePoint list but have a Sheet Name column that you can filter on.  Create new SharePooint list views to identify which sheet the rows came from.  Do not link to the .xlsx file as that will simply open the spread sheet.  You need to link to the SharePoint list view which is an .aspx page.

Comment: I understand that.  My question is about navigation on SharePoint pages. I want to create a launch page that takes you to different lists, which are on different pages.  Similar to the navigation interface in an html page. 
A page could have five links for example, 
Finance
R&D
Sales
G&A
Procurement
And each of these five links take you to a different list. I do not want to navigate from left frame.

Comment: Add a new content editor web part to your page.  Use the ribbon to insert hyperlinks.  Paste in the URL to the list view you wish the link to open.  Repeat for as many links as you like and save the page.

Comment: I tried that but then it opens the lists in Excel and not as list in SP. And since we are trying to avoid multiple versions of Excel files, I do not want the user to be able to open it in Excel.

Comment: At this point for my customers I’d want to screen share to see what’s going on.  Is there an option to upload screen shots on here?  Can you also provide example logs the users are clicking on and where you are getting those from?